# How can I pass some additional variables to a replacement function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have this structure

```
function foo() {
    var obj = [];
    var text = '...';
    text = text.replace(/.../g,matching_fn);
}

function matching_fn($match, $match1, $match2) {
    // i need obj here
}
```

I tried `matching_fn use (obj)` in the replace, but that didnt work.

How can I pass additional variables into my matching_fn?

Comment: Easiest way would be to define `matching_fn` *inside* `foo`

Comment: dang! I completely forgot functions inside functions in javascript :D thx